# cakephp - disable automatic input type detection using form helper

Tags: jquery, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I have an input in my form which is of the type DATE in my database.

When I use the form helper like this:

```
echo $this->Form->input('join_date', array('class'=>'datepicker', 'default'=>'Start Date*'));
```

Cake detects that this input is a DATE in the database and changes it into 3 dropdown inputs, for month, day and year. This is what's it's meant to do but I want to use the jquery datepicker plugin which requires that this input is just a normal input with jquery attached.

I could just type the html and not use the helper. Or I could use a different name instead of join_date and then just make sure I tie the info it collects up with the correct field when I'm saving, but it would be most handy if you could somehow disable the auto detection this field only. I've checked the manual but no mention that I could spot.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CakePHP tries to detect input type based on the name of the field the input is being created for, but you can override type:

```
 echo $this->Form->input('join_date', array('type' => 'text', 'class'=>'datepicker', 'default'=>'Start Date*'));
```